# Запись в файл в случае его отсутствия, а также чтение из него строки

Tags: c#, файлы, io

Суть вопроса такова: программно нужно открыть файл (если его нету, то создать), после чего записать данные из файла (`txt`) в переменную. Однако выходит сообщение об ошибке, что файл уже открыт другим процессом. Как его закрыть после открытия (открытие - проверка на наличие файла вообще) и считать из него данные?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        try
        {
            File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
            firstRun = false;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            File.Create(path);
            firstRun = true;
        }
        language = File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
    bool firstRun;
    string language;
    string path = @"D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\TrainingExersice\TrainingExersice\bin\Debug\started.txt";
```

Comment: Понимаете, товарищ, `File.ReadAllText(...)` внутри себя открывает заданный файл на чтение, потом читает весь его контент, а после - закрывает. Понятное дело, что при попытке вызова данного метода на уже открытый файл вылезет исключение ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Чуть позже приду домой и предложу Вам немного иной подход к решению задачи)

Comment: Странно файл после дейсвия закрывается а пишет что ещё используется

Comment: Буду ждать ответа

Comment: И где вы его закрываете? File.Open открывает FileStream, а его надо диспозить (либо использовать using), где это у вас? Вот [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx) использования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, я немного опоздал и [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857351/248572) уже дал [@Denis Bubnov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189339/denis-bubnov). Очень советую к прочтению ссылки, оставленные в нем. Они помогут Вам получше понять принцип работы с файлами.

---

### Почему так происходит?

Как Вам уже объяснили в соседнем ответе, открывая файл, Вы создали `FileStream`, который теперь уже использует указанный ресурс и не дает никому постороннему к нему доступа. Подробнее - по ссылкам в соседнем ответе

---

### Как быть?

Теперь же давайте поближе подойдем к решению конкретно Вашей задачи. Я бы переписал код, который находится у Вас в инициализаторе формы, как-то так:

```
string defaultLanguage = "eng";
if (firstRun = !File.Exists(path))
    File.WriteAllText(path, defaultLanguage = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to use English language?", "Language selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes ? "eng" : "rus");
language = firstRun ? defaultLanguage : File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Коротко и ясно)
Давайте все же пройдемся построчно и посмотрим, что происходит (для Вашего лучшего понимания):

1. `string defaultLanguage = "eng";`
   Я добавил переменную, в которую
   Вам необходимо записать дефолтное значение, как я понял, языка,
   которое будет использовано в случае отсутствия файла
2. `if (firstRun = !File.Exists(path))`
   Запишем в Вашу переменную
   `firstRun` значение, которое будет обратным результату функции,
   проверяющей, существует ли указанный файл. И в том случае, если файл
   не существовал, то перейдем к выполнению следующей строчки:
   `File.WriteAllText(path, defaultLanguage = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to use English language?", "Language selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes ? "eng" : "rus");`
   Данная функция
   создаст файл по указанному пути `path` (если бы он уже существовал,
   то она бы его попросту перезаписала) и запишет в него заданное нами
   значение `defaultLanguage`
   Как Вы указали в комментариях, Вы будете исходить из `DialogResult`, так что я подправил код. Тем самым перед записью `defaultLanguage` в файл, мы вызываем `MessageBox`, спрашивая пользователя, хочет ли он использовать английский язык, так что при возвращении `DialogResult.Yes` в `defaultLanguage` запишется `eng`, иначе - `rus`.
3. `language = firstRun ? defaultLanguage :
   File.ReadAllText(path);`
    В переменную `language` запишем
   значение из нашего файла (а если же мы его только что
   модифицировали, то сразу закинем туда значение по умолчанию)

---

Я также советую обернуть блок работы с файлом в `try...catch`, ибо мы не можем гарантировать, что за ту миллисекунду с проверки существования файла он куда-нибудь не исчезнет)

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог решить Вам поставленную задачу)

Comment: Разжевал так разжевал ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ думаю, после этого вопросов возникнуть не должно.

Comment: @DenisBubnov надеюсь, совместно наши 2 ответа помогут человеку понять основы работы с файлами) Вы собрали очень хороший теоретический материал)

Comment: @DenisBubnov Да, кстати, не забывайте, что символ \ в комментариях и постах на SE надо экранировать (\\\), а то смайлик безруким вышел)

Comment: К сожелению обратное тут моя вина я тут обясню в чём суть но буду дальше думать сам если всё получится. 
У меня идея такова: Происходит запуск чисто exe файла при первом запуске. Так как запуск первый значит посторонних файлов ещё нету. Запускаем проект - создаем файл (временно пустой) - от пользователя ждем ответа (там dialogresult) и если он согласен на англ то в файл запишем eng а если нет то rus. И в последующем запуске программы открывать файл так как он уже есть и чатать какой там текст и от этого зависит какой язык будет использоваться

Comment: Если на этом всё я отмечаю готовый ответ или теоретический материал)??

Comment: @AquaGF пожалуйста, всегда полностью расписывайте желаемое в Вашем вопросе) Подправил ответ и добавил туда вызов `MessageBox` и, как следствие, взаимодействие с возвращаемым `DialogResult`)

Answer (score 3):

Правильнее использовать оператор `using`. Оператор `using` *правильно* вызывает метод `Dispose` и позволяет освободить неуправляемым ресурс (в нашем случае файл).

Вот пример кода, демонстрирующий работу с файлом:

```
// путь к файлу и строка записываемая в файл
string path = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Записываемая строка");

// если файл существует
if (File.Exists(path))
{
   // откроем файл в режиме записи 
    using (var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) 
    {
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length); // запишем объявленную переменную в файл
    }
}
else
{
    // если файла нет - создадим файл
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length); // запишем объявленную переменную в файл
    }
}

// теперь ошибки не будет при чтении (если есть права на чтение)
var fromFile = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [Оператор using](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)
- [Метод File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Метод File.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Метод File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx)

Я лишь показал вам то, как нужно работать с методами `File.Open` и `File.Create` через `using`, а также есть метод `File.Exists` - проверяющий наличие файла. Ваш код не совсем рабочий. Даже если вы создадите файл, и ничего не запишите, то что будет в нем? Правильно - ничего. Поэтому смысла в чтении пустого файла я не вижу. Мой ответ - это пример того, как нужно работать с файлом. Поэтому, основываясь на моем ответе - внедрите мой код в свой код. Также, не будет лишним обернуть его в блок `try...catch`.

Вот простой пример того, как прочитать данные из существующего файла в переменную:

```
// путь к файлу
string path = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
// сюда поместим прочитанный текст из файла
string fromFile;

// если файл существует
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    // читаем из файла (если есть права на чтение)
    fromFile = File.ReadAllText(path);
}
```

Думаю, что должно быть понятно.

Comment: Записываемая строка какой переменной обозначена в моем коде?

Comment: @AquaGF у вас нет записываемой строки. Я лишь показал вам то, как нужно работать с методами `Open` и `Create` через `using`. Ваш код не рабочий. Даже если вы создадите файл, и ничего не запишите, то что будет в нем? Правильно - ничего. Поэтому смысла в чтении пустого файла я не вижу. Мой ответ - это пример того, как нужно работать с файлом, основываясь на котором - внедрить в свой код.

Comment: @AquaGF товарищ показал Вам просто принципы работы всего этого дела. Если помощь ещё нужна конкретно по Вашей проблеме - оформлю ответ через 5-10 минут

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Да за обобщение спасибо автору вопроса, но мне честно говоря не помешал бы код с пояснением что где к чему

Comment: @AquaGF а вы комментарии же видите в коде? Просто используйте готовые методы. Первым делом проверили, что файл существует (не через `try-catch`) с помощью `File.Exists` - если файл есть - можем его открыть, причем даже тут мы можем вторым параметром указать режим `OpenOrCreate`, но я решил немного детально показать логику. Третий параметр - это режим (мы его открываем на запись, а можно сразу `ReadWrite`, но тут снова для ясности показал с условиями). Использование `using` позволяет освободить неуправляемым ресурс - в вашем случае файл. Это краткое пояснение, надеюсь понятное.

Comment: Да комментарий снизу видел и да сейчас буду реализовывать эти методы в мой код. Как мне вот тут в условии есть ли файл добавить правильно считывание строки из файла в переменную